# Declaration of a character array in C - Clash between Norminette and Compiler

Tags: arrays, c, string, character, declaration

I am hoping somebody could please clarify what I am doing wrong.
I am trying to replicate the strcpy function in C.

The exercise requires us to create two loop through a src string and replace the content at each corresponding index at the destination string.
My issue is when I create the test function in int main() I initialise a character array and assign it some content. It compiles fine however I get a norminette error:

```
// Method 1

char    str1[5] = "abcde";// Error: DECL_ASSIGN_LINE   Declaration and assignation on a single line

char    str2[5] = "fghij"; //Error: DECL_ASSIGN_LINE Declaration and assignation on a single line
```

If I initialise and assign like bellow, Norminette is ok but I get a compilation error:

```
// Method 2

char    str1[5] = "abcde";

char    str2[5] = "fghij"; 


str1[] = "abcde"; // error: expected expression before ‘]’ token ... (with an arrow pointing to ] bracket) 

str2[] = "fghij"; // error: expected expression before ‘]’ token ... (with an arrow pointing to ] bracket)
```

```
// Method 3

char    str1[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','\0'}; // Error: DECL_ASSIGN_LINE   Declaration and assignation on a single line

char    str2[] = {'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', '\0'};//Error: DECL_ASSIGN_LINE Declaration and assignation on a single line
```

I have also tried various methods including str[5] = "abcde" after declaration with no success.
My question is how can I declare these character arrays to satisfy both the norminette and compiler?

Also is my understand that in C, a character array and a string are interchangeable concepts?
Thank you

Comment: I don't know anything about "norminette" You need a array of size 6 for your sample strings. Using 5 doesn't provide room for the null terminator. `char str1[] = "abcde";` would be a common and generally acceptable way of doing this. `char str1[6] = "abcde";` will work for C, but is more fragile. These are initialization, not assignment as your norminette seems to be claiming. 'char str1[6]"; str1[] = "abcde";` is illegal C. `char str[6]; strcpy(str, "abcde")` might satisfy norminette, but `char str1[] = "abcde";` is better code for initialization from a literal.

Comment: In C. a character array and a string are _related, but not interchangeable_ concepts. A **null terminated** character array is the convention of how strings are generally handled. It is possible to use char arrays in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

In method 2:

```
str1[] = "abcde"; // error:
```

is an *assignment*, so it's invalid. The `[]` syntax can only be used in a *definition*. More on this below.

---

Method 3 is fine. Whoever is flagging this is wrong.

---

In method 1 [and other places]:

```
char str1[5] = "abcde";
```

is wrong because it should be:

```
char str1[6] = "abcde";
```

to account for the EOS (0x00) string terminator at the end.

An alternate would be:

```
char str1[] = "abcde";
```

And, you did this [more or less] in method 3:

```
char str1[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', '\0'};
```

AFAICT, this was flagged by the external tool (*not* the compiler?). It is a perfectly valid alternative.

Answer (score 0):

> Also is my understand that in C, a character array and a string are interchangeable concepts?

No.  In C, a *string* is a sequence of character values including a 0-valued terminator.  The string `"abcde"` would be represented by the sequence `{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 0}`.  That terminator is how the various string handling routines like `strlen` and `strcpy` know where the end of the string is.

Strings (including string literals like `"abcde"`) are *stored* in arrays of character type, but not every array of character type stores a string - it could be a character sequence with no 0-valued terminator, or it could be a character sequence including multiple 0-valued bytes.

In order to store a string of N characters, the array has to be *at least* N+1 elements wide:

```
char str1[6] = "abcde";  // 5 printing characters plus 0 terminator
char str1[6] = "fghij";
```

You can declare the array without an explicit size, and the size (including the +1 for the terminator) will be determined from the size of the initializer:

```
char str1[] = "abcde"; // will allocate 6 elements for str1
char str2[] = "fghij";
```

I've found the [documentation for Norminette](https://github.com/gdamion/Norminette/blob/master/norme.en.pdf) and ... *ugh*.

I get that your school wants everyone to follow a common coding standard; that makes it easier to analyze and grade everyone's code.  But some of its rules are just plain *weird* and non-idiomatic and, ironically, encourage bad style.  If I'm interpreting it correctly, it wants you to write your initializers as

```
char str1[] 
  = "abcde";
```

or something equally bizarre.  Nobody does that.

One way to get around the problem is to not initialize the array in the declaration, but assign it separately using `strcpy`:

```
char str1[6]; // size is required since we don't have an initializer
char str2[6];

strcpy( str1, "abcde" );
strcpy( str2, "fghij" );
```

You cannot use `=` to assign whole arrays outside of a declaration (initialization is not the same thing as assignment).  IOW, you can't write something like

```
str1 = "abcde";
```

as a statement.

You either have to use a library function like `strcpy` or `strncpy` (for strings) or `memcpy` (for things that aren't strings), or you have to assign each element individually:

```
str1[0] = 'a';
str1[1] = 'b';
str1[2] = 'c';
...
```